# Haskell: Getting error when accepting string input in user defined function

Tags: haskell

I'm a newbie in Haskell. Was trying a code to take input string in user defined function and further perform tasks as per argument passed to function in main.

```
main :: IO()
main=do
{
    print(f 2)
}
f::Int->Int
f n=do
{
    inp<-getLine;
    if (inp=="hello") then (n+2);
    else                   (n);
}
```

Since this function takes int and returns int, I defined it as Int->Int. However I feel something's missing.
I'm getting the following error:-

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
main.hs:9:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘IO b0’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: inp <- getLine
      In the expression:
        do inp <- getLine
           if (inp == "hello") then (n + 2) else (n)
      In an equation for ‘f’:
          f n
            = do inp <- getLine
                 if (inp == "hello") then (n + 2) else (n)
  |
9 |     inp<-getLine;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
main.hs:10:29: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b0’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: (n + 2)
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        if (inp == "hello") then (n + 2) else (n)
      In the expression:
        do inp <- getLine
           if (inp == "hello") then (n + 2) else (n)
   |
10 |     if (inp=="hello") then (n+2);
   |                             ^^^
main.hs:11:29: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b0’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: (n)
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        if (inp == "hello") then (n + 2) else (n)
      In the expression:
        do inp <- getLine
           if (inp == "hello") then (n + 2) else (n)
   |
11 |     else                   (n);
   |                             ^
```

How to rectify this error??

Comment: Your code looks like C a lot. Take a look at some existing code snippets to see how to format code in Haskell. For example spacing around operators, unnecessary parentheses, curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `do` block almost always indicates that you are defining a monadic computation(1). Therefore the type of `f` has to be `Int -> IO Int` (`IO` is induced by the use of `getLine` here). Additionally, since the result has to be contained in a monadic context, you should wrap `n+2` and `n` with `return`.

So the final code of `f` should be

```
f :: Int -> IO Int
f n = do
    inp <- getLine
    if inp == "hello" then return (n + 2)
    else                   return n
```

Note that the use of `f` in `main` has to be adjusted accordingly.

---

<sub>(1)sometimes applicative, but anyway</sub>

Comment: Thank you for you help. You inputs are greatly appreciated, especially regarding the fact that it looks like C code. I will try to improve on it.